# Python contour plot vs pcolormesh for probability map

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have two arrays of points that I need to plot that I have stored in arrays, but at each of these points there is a probability of some event happening so each has a value ranging from 0 to 1. My idea was to find a way to assign these probabilities to their respective (x,y) coordinate and display it as a heatmap. The code to plot this is as follows:

```
plt.pcolormesh(xcoord,ycoord,des_mag)
plt.show()
```

Where xcoord and ycoord are arrays. I could only make this run if I made des_mag a 2D array, in this case a 2000x2000 array with only entries on the diagonal since xcoord and ycoord each contain 2000 coordinates. All the des_mag values vary from 0 to 1. When I run this the output is simply a graph with a solid background and one tiny grid point in the corner with a different color. I'm 95% confident the issue is my lack of understanding on what it is I need to input for the plot, but I can't seem to find many examples for clarity on the issue. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More information about your data would be helpful. In general [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is useful. Are your x,y data points already in a grid? Or are they more-or-less randomly scattered in 2d space? This well determine how easy it is to plot a heatmap. As you've realized, `pcolormesh` and similar functions require a 2d array as input.

Comment: `pcolormesh` also needs the x and y coordinates as 2d fields. With your 1D coordinate values you can get them doing something like this: `x2d,y2d = np.meshgrid(xcoord,ycoord)` and then `plt.pcolormesh(x2d,y2d,des_mag)`.